# Multiple values with <Select> List

Tags: php, list, html-select

I've created a list of 4 product categories. It's working fine and passing all the       values to the next page.

Code is:

```
echo "<tr><td>Product Category* </td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "<select size=\"1\" name=\"pc\" id=\"pc\">"; 
echo "<option value=\"0\">Product Category</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"Hair\">Hair</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"Skin\">Skin</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"Nail\">Nail</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"Eyes\">Eyes</options>"; 
echo "</select></td>";
```

I want this list to transfer 4 more values (product category IDs) with the current values to the next page also.

- for Hair ID is: 77
- for Skin ID is: 88
- for Nail ID is: 99
- for Eyes ID is: 66

Comment: Why not just use those numbers as the option value?

Comment: Juhana is right. Pass the product ids through the option value attribute.

Comment: Sorry guys I wasn't clear enough. I want both the values Hair and 77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<tr><td>Product Category* </td>";

echo "<td>";

echo "<select size=\"1\" name=\"pc\" id=\"pc\">"; 
echo "<option value=\"0\">Product Category</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"77-Hair\">Hair</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"88-Skin\">Skin</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"99-Nail\">Nail</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"66-Eyes\">Eyes</options>"; 
echo "</select></td>";
```

and split value for "-" on server side

Comment: That seem to work. Many thanks Xcoder. appreciate your help. I haven't seen this answer anywhere. Cheers !!!!

Answer (score 0):

In case, you don't understand `Juhana`'s comment, this is what he means.

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<select size=\"1\" name=\"pc\" id=\"pc\">"; 
echo "<option value=\"0\">Product Category</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"77\">Hair</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"88\">Skin</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"99\">Nail</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"66\">Eyes</options>"; 
echo "</select></td>";
```

However, if you'd like to do this via a JS / jQuery solution.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#pc').change(function() {
        var cat_id = $('option:selected', this).data(category_id);
        $('#cat_id').val(cat_id);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<select size=\"1\" name=\"pc\" id=\"pc\">"; 
    echo "<option value=\"0\">Product Category</options>"; 
    echo "<option data-category_id=\"77\" value=\"Hair\">Hair</options>"; 
    echo "<option data-category_id=\"88\" value=\"Skin\">Skin</options>"; 
    echo "<option data-category_id=\"99\" value=\"Nail\">Nail</options>"; 
    echo "<option data-category_id=\"66\" value=\"Eyes\">Eyes</options>"; 
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"cat_id\" name=\"category_id\" />";
```

Comment: I dont even understand the question this guy is asking.  I wont even ask why he isnt just instantiating a view component with this data. Its not unobtrusive to be creating code like this.  The PHP should be handling post/get and returning server values and should just allow the JS to handle component population.

Comment: Hi Nitro, sorry mate I am not expert like you. I've just started learning PHP and appreciate some help from you guys. Moderator has ranked -1 because may ba I was not able to explain my question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't put these id's for value?

```
echo "<tr><td>Product Category* </td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "<select size=\"1\" name=\"pc\" id=\"pc\">"; 
echo "<option value=\"0\">Product Category</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"77\">Hair</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"88\">Skin</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"99\">Nail</options>"; 
echo "<option value=\"66\">Eyes</options>"; 
echo "</select></td>";
```

Comment: Many thanks Rahnamafard, I am sorry I wasn't clear enough I need both the values Hair and 77.

Comment: you can use `Hair 77` for the value and in the php file use `$rslt=explode(" ",$_POST['sample_name']);`. this function slice your string where it have space. (return an array like `$rslt[0]` ,  `$rslt[1]` , ...). Also see " http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php ".

Comment: `$rslt=explode(" ",$_POST['sample_name']);`